# Data storing in native code

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I want to write a vector class (or something other) on C++. And I want to use its methods from Java. How to do this? I want to use JNI for this purpose. But javah generate me c prototypes. I want to store data in the C++ use area and use in java only an interface without fields. So, the problem is how to store the vector data in C-code.

**Note:**

Simply speaking, I need to wrap C++ interface by JNI and to have this interface in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have a C-callable wrapper around your C++ code.  The approach is similar to how you would allow a C++ library to be usable from pure C.  Here is a simple example (**with no error checking at all -- do not use for real production code**):

```
void * MyVectorCreate()
{
    return new MyVector<int>();
}

void MyVectorAdd(void * vector, int item)
{
    static_cast<MyVector<int> *>(vector)->Add(item);
}

void MyVectorDestroy(void * vector)
{
    delete static_cast<MyVector<int> *>(vector);
}
```

Comment: But where to store the result from MyVectorCreate()? And where to take void * vecto for MyVectorAdd and MyVectorDestroy?

Comment: It looks like in JNI you need to handle `void *` as a `long`, casting back and forth as needed from C to Java and Java to C.

Comment: So, how MyVectorCreate should look like in Java? and when to call MyVectorDestroy

Comment: I'm not a JNI expert, but presumably you would return 64-bit longs instead of void* from your C code and capture those as Java longs.  When you need to make a call back into the C code, you'd pass that long around.  Inside the C code, you'd turn the long back into a MyVector pointer and use it as you would a normal object.